# Cannot seem to access the Children of my StackPanels inside a Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, stackpanel

this worked when i created a listbox dynamically.. but now that i'm making everything strictly through WPF.. this doesn't seem to work and i have no idea why.. it seems correct to me and i feel like maybe i'm missing something?

the error i'm getting is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

wpf code:

```
                   <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxT10">
                        <ListBoxItem>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                                    
                                <TextBox FontSize="14" Text="" Width="120"/>
                                <TextBox FontSize="14" Text="" Width="40" MaxLength="3"/>
                                <TextBox FontSize="14" Text="" Width="413"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListBoxItem>
                        ...a bunch of the same listboxitems...
```

C# code:

```
            int a = 0;
            foreach (var item in ListBoxT10.Items)
            {
                StackPanel tempStackPanel = item as StackPanel;

                Console.WriteLine(tempStackPanel.Children.Count);  //this even errors.. i guess it's not finding the children

                string pName = (tempStackPanel.Children[0] as TextBox).Text;  //error
                string tri = (tempStackPanel.Children[1] as TextBox).Text;  //error
                string stats = (tempStackPanel.Children[2] as TextBox).Text;  //error
```

EDIT: i'm realizing that it's because the item in ListBoxT10.Items are actually "ListBoxItem"'s.. but now i can't get the children of listboxitems... ugh =[

Answer (score 0):

```
                ListBoxItem lbi = (ListBoxItem)(ListBoxT10.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(a));
                StackPanel sp = lbi.Content as StackPanel;

                string pName = (sp.Children[1] as TextBox).Text;
                string tri = (sp.Children[2] as TextBox).Text;
                string stats = (sp.Children[3] as TextBox).Text;
```

i forgot about the listboxitem.........didn't think that would register as an object too